# Show BottomSheet With Data From API Call Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I am familiar with how to use a bottom sheet but my use case is different from examples and implementations I have seen online.

Let me explain - I have a horizontal date picker where when the user selects or clicks on a date, I'll show a white sheet from the bottom of the screen to half way point. This sheet will contain the selected date and I have to send that date to an api to get all the details to be displayed.

The use case is different because not all dates will have data returned from the api, so I'll have to show a simple text like `No data returned for dd/mm/yyyy`. I don't think you can use an ativity or fragment in bottom sheet as ideally I would want full control on how contents are displayed.

Is it possible to make an activity or fragment to function as a bottom sheet with full functionality or I can add a `Java class as controller to the bottomsheet dialog, where I can make my network calls`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by looking at `BottomSheetDialog Fragment` class and written my own implementation of this. Thank you for future answers too.